# convertir timestamp UNIX a normal en nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo este problema.

De una consulta a un API en nodejs, obtengo un timestamp en formato UNIX el cual necesito convertirlo a formato legible, el código que hasta ahora tengo es este.

```
var hrs = 1600734361378;
var s = new Date(hrs).toLocaleTimeString("es-MX");
```

El resultado esperado es: 19:26:01 y lo que obtengo es: 0:26:01, solo fala la hora, creo que todo esto radica en el formato, pero no logro encontrar como, lo agradeceré mucho si me pueden ayudar.

Comment: ¿Y qué zona horaria tiene tu sistema? El valor devuelto se corresponde con UTC. El método `toLocaleTimeString()` no cambiará la zona horaria de la representación, solo dará formato (que no es zona horaria) a la salida.

Comment: Si estás en México, tu zona horaria en verano es UTC-5. 1600734361378 en UNIX time es 22 de Septiempre, 00:26:01 UTC (+0). Al restarle las 5 horas que corresponden obtienes las 19:26:01